# C++ hash table implementation with collision handling

Tags: c++, hashtable, hashmap

What is a good C++ library for hash tables / hash maps similar to what java offers. I have worked with Google Sparsehash, but it has no support for collisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to those mentioned in other answers, you could try [MCT](https://launchpad.net/libmct)'s `closed_hash_map` or `linked_hash_map`.  It is internally similar to Google SparseHash, but doesn't restrict values used and has some other functional advantages.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "no support for collisions", though.  Both Google SparseHash and similarly implemented MCT of course handle collisions fine, though differently than Java's `HashMap`.

Answer (score 6):

Use [std::unordered_map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982522.aspx) (or unordered_multimap), which despite its name is a hash table - it will be part of the next C++ standard, and is available in most current C++  implementations. Do not use the classes with `hash` in their names that your implementation may provide - they are not and will not be standard.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_multimap.html

or

`std::tr1::unordered_multimap`